# Handle new-line in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

There is a requirement to preserve the new line character in a text area.

I've written a filter as:

`modAFUI.filter('nl2br', function(){
    return function(input){
        return input?input.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'):'';
}
});`

and the HTML output as:

`<textarea ng-model="record.data.Note_Note | nl2br" style="min-height: 200px; width: 90%" placeholder=""/>`

The above does not work. After saving the record, I still get the entered text as single line without any breaks. Is there anything that am missing?

Thanks

Shaddy.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to preserve the line breaks of text displayed/entered in a text area. Remove this useless nl2br filter and tell us how you determine that you're losing them. Where do you look?

Comment: Ok, so I am entering text details in a text area with breaks; however, when I save the record and view it, it shows as a single line.

Comment: **where** does it show as a single line? Which tool do you use to look at the saved record? If you're reloading the record and displaying its value in HTML, that's expected since HTML considers newlines as white space. That's where you need to transform the newlines to <br>, or to use the appropriate CSS class to preserve line breaks. Not when saving the string.